# Shifts in x-axis datetime with ggplot

Tags: datetime, ggplot2, filter, x-axis

I have two data-frames, both have water level data associated with a date & time. Below is a sample portion of said data-frames.

```
   DateTime             WL
   7/23/2023 09:30      435
   7/23/2023 09:35      436
   7/23/2023 09:40      435
```

Upon loading both data-frames, I use the function ymd_hms for the date-time in order to graph it with ggplot. When using ggplot, I do use scale_x_datetime, with the sub-functions of breaks and labels and nothing else. I first noticed that there was a shift when I was trying to filter the data to smaller portions of time. This shift is 4 hours as I would filter between 8:00 and 18:00 and the data-frame would then have data from 12:00 to 22:00. However when I graphed this smaller dataset the date-time would match up. Furthermore when I was creating geom_rects on the figure to highlight periods of sampling and found that the date-times I was specifying were off from again by 4 hours.

I have done some research and found that the time-zone may be responsible but early attempts found no solutions. For reference this data was collected in the Chicago-Standard Timezone.

Any help is appreciated!

I have tried to update the time-zone but everytime I do I get the error message "unknown timezone" and I can't seem to find a reference list for time-zones.